# Dojo: show/hide info inside a datagrid cell

Tags: datagrid, dojo, height, hide, show

I am using dojo 1.7.2 and I have a datagrid. In one of the columns I have a long description that I want to show or hide when a "see more" link is clicked. I got all of that working with a formatter but when the description expands the datagrid's outer container does not get taller (in other words the rows below just get pushed down out of site. Is there anyway to change the height of the grid when I click on my show/hide (can the grid be redrawn? If so how?)

Update: I have created a js fiddle that shows what I want to do. You will see there is hidden text and when you click, it shows, but the rows at the bottom are pushed out of view:

http://jsfiddle.net/erayK/

Because I have to include some code, here is the formatter I used:

```
function formatLink(value){
    // value 0: title, value 1: description, value 2: url
    return '<a href="'+ value[2] +'">'+value[0]+'</a><br /><div style="display:none;" id="' + value[0] + '">'+value[1]+'</div><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(\'' + value[0] +'\'); return false;">show or hide</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution, I can override the dojo styling that cuts off the stuff at the bottom and add a scrollbar using:

```
.dojoxGridContent {
    overflow: auto;
}
```